# Livebindings with contained objects

Tags: delphi, object, livebindings

I need bind a object non visual with TEdit.

```
TCountry = class
  FName: string;
  ...
end;

TCity = class
  FName: string;
  FCountry: TCountry;
  ...
end;
```

I use livebindings with TDataGeneratorAdapter and TAdapterBindSource and I don't how to access: city.country.name in livebindings to show in TEdit.

my problem is how to bind (or access) city.country.name in the livebindings. I know bind city.name in the TEdit because city.name is a string, but city.country.name I don't get work. ***sorry my english :)

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE8

Comment: Sorry I have not used XE8. I did it with XE2, but maybe it is the same. See me solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Delphi XE2. I think it should work in XE8.

Right Click on the TDataGeneratorAdaptor component.

Although they don't make it clear, what you are doing here is mimicking a database with your class as a record. It can't read your class (since that will only exist at run time, and we are in design mode here) so you must explicitly add your fields to mimic, say, the TCity class. So you would select Add a field and enter the name as FName and select the field data (none) of type ftString.

With country you have a problem. Really you need to merge the classes if you can. Otherwise you will need to create a separate TDataGeneratorAdaptor for TCountry, remembering that you are in effect generating what amounts to an in-memory database.

It is worth looking at Database examples and thinking of your objects in those terms.